# ¿Cómo evitar asignar manualmente las variables de un split al crear un objeto a partir de un archivo CSV en Java?

Tags: java, poo, archivo, csv, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy desarrollando un programa en Java donde necesito leer un archivo CSV que contiene información sobre contratos offline. Utilizo el método leerContratosOffline() para extraer los datos relevantes y guardarlos en listas para su posterior uso.

El problema es que actualmente estoy asignando manualmente las variables después de hacer un split en cada línea del archivo CSV. Esto me obliga a actualizar el código cada vez que se agrega un nuevo campo al archivo CSV, lo cual es muy tedioso y propenso a errores.

```
 public static void leerContratosOffline() {
        // ...
    
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFilePath))) {
            // ...
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] contrato = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
  String tipoDeContrato = contrato[0].toUpperCase(); // Tipo de Contrato
     int idEmpresa = Integer.parseInt(contrato[2]);
.
.
  // Crear el objeto Contrato y agregarlo a la lista
                // Asignación manual de variables para crear el objeto Contrato
                // ...
    
                // Resto del código para crear el objeto Contrato y agregarlo a las listas
                // ...
            }
            // ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // ...
    }
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Existe alguna forma de evitar tener que asignar manualmente todas las variables después de hacer el split? Me gustaría encontrar una solución que me permita mapear automáticamente los datos del archivo CSV a un objeto Contrato, de manera que si se agrega un nuevo campo al archivo CSV en el futuro, no tenga que modificar manualmente el código.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier sugerencia o ejemplo de cómo podría abordar este problema de manera más eficiente y escalable en Java.

¡Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Si tienes el nombre del campo en el csv puedes usar un objeto en java que tenga los mismos atributos, puedes usar reflection y asignarlos con `"set" + NombreCampo`. Si no quieres ni tener que crear el atributo en el objeto "a mano" puedes usar java para crear la clase en tiempo de construcción (depende un poco de qué framework estés usando o si es java puro, tendrás que investigar más tú mismo). Esto es muy por encima, lo que pides es bastante más complejo y requiere más código del que me entra en un comentario :)

Comment: Hay un montón de librerías que te permiten hacer esto con un par de líneas de código. Creas un POJO y mapeas el `.csv` a una lista de objetos de dicho POJO. Si la cosa evoluciona y aparecen nuevas versiones del `.csv` con nuevas propiedades, sólo agregas esas nuevas propiedades al POJO. [Aquí hay un listado](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison) de las diversas posibilidades que tienes, escoge alguna, intenta un código y si tienes problemas entonces pregunta basándote en el problema concreto.

Comment: [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/2.16/csv) es una de las más usadas en Java para resolver este tipo de problemas. Si no te conviene esa, mira en el listado, hay varias.

Comment: Hola Enrique, bienvenido, tal vez no esté entendiendo el problema, así que toma mi comentario con pinzas, pero se me ocurre que podrías modificar la clase **Contrato** para que reciba un array de datos, y en caso de que haya modificaciones, hacer los cambios solo en el constructor.